# Is there a way to update cache storage data after POST request in offline and display that data in view

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, workbox, offline-caching

I am using PWA & workbox for offline functionality where GET requests are being stored in Cachestorage & POST requests in INDEXED DB with workbox background sync.

here is a peice of code for **GET request storing in cache**

```
registerRoute(
    new RegExp('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com'),
    new NetworkFirst({
        cacheName: 'users',
        networkTimeoutSeconds: 15,
        plugins: [new ExpirationPlugin({ maxAgeSeconds: 43200 })]
    }),
    'GET'
);
```

in offline **for POST requests** which make a queue in INDEXED DB and sync once user is online

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
    // Check if this is a request for an image
    if (event.request.clone().method === 'POST') {
        const bgSyncLogic = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await fetch(event.request.clone());
                return response;
            } catch (error) {
                await queue.pushRequest({ request: event.request });
                return error;
            }
        };
        event.respondWith(bgSyncLogic());
    }
});
```

I have a list called *users* in cache which needs to be updated and displayed in view after POST(when a new user is added) request is cached in INDEXED DB in offline. what is the best way to update cache stored list?
How can we do it dynamically which works for all POST requests?
How do we sync/fetch get list(after workbox background sync queue executes POST request to server) in view once user is back online?

Answer (score 1):

This might be to late but I am dealing with the same issue at the moment. I'm not sure the solution I just came up with is ideal but it seems to work.

The idea is to...

1. get the cached Response's body
2. update it with the new data
3. create a new Response (can't modify existing) with the modified body and the status/statusText/headers copied from the cached response
4. replace the existing cached Response with the new Response

Here's an example of how I did it.

```
    var _updateData;
    async function postError()
    {
        let cache = await caches.open('workbox-runtime-cachename');
        let entry = await cache.match('/request/toupdate');
        let oldData = JSON.parse(await entry.text());

        oldData.Avatar = _updateData.Avatar == null ? oldData.Avatar : _updateData.Avatar;
        oldData.Email = _updateData.Email;
        oldData.FullName = _updateData.FullName;
        oldData.GeolocationLevel = _updateData.GeolocationLevel;
        oldData.PhoneNumber = _updateData.PhoneNumber;
        oldData.PublicProfile = _updateData.PublicProfile;
        oldData.Theme = _updateData.Theme;
    
        let responseOptions = {};
        responseOptions.status = entry.status;
        responseOptions.statusText = entry.statusText;
        let header = new Headers();

        entry.headers.forEach((value, key) => {
            header.append(key, value)
        });
        responseOptions.headers = header;

        let updatedResponse = new Response(JSON.stringify(oldData), responseOptions)
        let keys = await cache.keys()
        keys.forEach((key) => {
            if(key.url === `${document.location.origin}/request/toupdate`)
            {
                cache.put(key, updatedResponse);
            }
        });
    }
```

The code is just for one specific POST request and I haven't cleaned it up much but it does work.

Obviously you'd need to put in real urls and cache names. You'd also probably want to have a more generic approach (like I'm planning on doing) so you don't have to write it for each individual POST request in your application.

If you've come up with a better solution, let me know. You'd think workbox would have something to handle this but I haven't found anything yet.